# Find out (in controller) which specific validation rule failed

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a user registration form with `email` field which acts as username and should be unique accross the application.

`User` model has following are validation rules for this field:

```
var $validate = array(
    'email' => array(
        'email' => array('rule' => 'email', 'allowEmpty' => false, 'last' => true, 'message' => 'Valid email address required'),
        'unique' => array('rule'=> 'isUnique', 'message' => 'Already exists'),
    ),
);
```

In my controller I want to check if it was the `'unique'` rule which has failed (to display a different form elements, like "Send password recovery email" button).

I can check whether `email` field was valid or not (`if (isset($this->User->validationErrors['email']))`), but **how do I check for specific rule failure**?

Looking for specific error message like  `if ($this->User->validationErrors['email'] == "Already exists")` just doesn't seem right (l10n etc.)...

Answer (score 6):

Have a read of http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html

Essentially you just have to use:

```
$errors = $this->ModelName->invalidFields();
```

Which will give you an array of all validation errors.

---

**Update (Custom Validation Rules):**

So we want to check if it's an email, and if it's unique - we want the following rules in the model:

CakePHP Validation : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html

Before the "return false" of each, we need to set somewhere that this validation rule failed. Easiest way: we can break the MVC convention, and use the configuration class (http://book.cakephp.org/view/924/The-Configuration-Class) and set it there, and access it accordingly in the controller.

```
Configure::write('UserValidationFail','email'); //for email before return false
Configure::write('UserValidationFail','isUnique'); //for unique before return false
```

And then access it from the controller via:

```
Configure::read('UserValidationFail');
```

Which will give you either 'email' or 'isUnique'.

Comment: I need to know that **specific rule** has failed. `$this->Model->invalidFields()` returns same `Model->validationErrors` array with error messages.

Comment: why would you wanna know that? usually it is only important whether it failed (!empty()) or passed (empty())!

Comment: Read question: _In my controller I want to check if it was the 'unique' rule which has failed (to display a different form elements, like "Send password recovery email" button)._ I.e. in case of this specific failure I want to display different form.

Comment: The only other way I can think of is to write your own custom validation rule, on failure it would return false and perhaps also set a global var / flatfile or something with the specific name of failed rule that you can access?

Comment: You could write this up with example as an answer.

Comment: Jeez why use configuration? Just set `$this->emailNotUnique = true` in model.

Comment: It was safer to go with configuration - wasn't sure if you'd want to access it in the views/helpers as well.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't point out which framework you're using (doesn't look like CodeIgniter). However, if $this->User->validationErrors['email'] returns a simple text string there's not much you can do with it.

Does the user object have any other properties? Might be a good idea to print_r it to see what's inside.

Answer (score 0):

It has Cakephp tags on the post. Don't validate data from controller, always try to do this in models and push this through to controllers and viewers instead...

Comment: Data is validated in model. I need to check validation result in controller (failure of specific rule).

Answer (score 0):

well, invalidFields() include both the fields  and the error messages. You can guess the rule by the error message, right?

Edit: it can be done this way:

```
$this->User->validationErrors['email'] == $this->User->validate['email']['unique']['message']
```

Comment: I mentioned in question that it is doubtful approach: _Looking for specific error message like if ($this->User->validationErrors['email'] == "Already exists") just doesn't seem right (l10n etc.)..._.

Comment: sorry, somehow I skipped that. 2 things: for l10n, cake actually won't automatically localize validation errors for you though (http://book.cakephp.org/view/1230/). To solve your problem: ($this->User->validationErrors['email'] == __("Already exists",true))

Comment: that's true, however comparing **messages** still isn't right; for example if copywriter would change error message couple years later (when original programmer is not around) we'll get a pretty nasty bug

Comment: I just realized it can be done this way: ($this->User->validationErrors['email'] == __($this->User->validate['email']['unique']['message'],true)). It's still comparing messages, but it's as elegant as it can get, I suppose.

Comment: Correct would be `$this->User->validationErrors['email'] == $this->User->validate['email']['unique']['message']` (because `validationErrors` contains already localized message. Edit your answer to reflect this approach.

Comment: uhm.. that's why I wrapped the right hand part in the translate function. I'm kind of confused here (?)

Comment: My point is: `validationErrors['email']` was just copied from `$this->User->validate['email']['unique']['message']` (by validation code) so no extra translation necessary.

Comment: yes, it was copied from validate array, but if you localize the way the cookbook recommends (in the link I post above), it will be different from $this->User->validate['email']['unique']['message'], which has the un-localized text. Anw, I'll update my answer to reflect the idea.

Comment: Yes, you're right, if it's localized in `invalidate()` then the comparison should as you suggest, with `__()` on the right side.